# Understanding lock scope

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

From this [link](http://inheritingjava.blogspot.in/2012/01/chapter-11-lock-scope.html), I understand "Since the lock() and unlock() method calls are explicit, we can move them anywhere, establishing any lock scope, from a single line of code to a scope that spans multiple methods"

So what I understand from the above statement is

```
public class Test {
    Lock l = new ReentrantLock();

    void myMethod1() {
        l.lock();
        // Do my stuff here
    }

    void myMethod2() {
        // Do more stuff here
        l.unlock();
    }
}
```

So basically 1 can call method1 and method2 in sequence and assume the call is thread safe.

I am not sure if it's true as said above.

What if somebody just calls method2 when i am already executing method1/method2 pair? Doesn't it complicate things.

I think a lock should be acquired and released in the function itself, before the control is returned from the function. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: `I think a lock should be acquired and released in the function itself, before the control is returned from the function.` It is a lot easier to do it this way but it isn't necessary with reentrantlock.

Comment: If you use [error-prone](http://errorprone.info/) with `LockMethod` and `UnlockMethod` annotations then you'll get a compile time check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer to first question:**

> What if somebody just calls method2 when i am already executing
>   method1/method2 pair? Doesn't it complicate things.

Suppose another thread calls the `unlock()` method on the `ReentrantLock` object **then `IllegalMonitorStateException` would be thrown**. Because the thread is not acquiring the lock and when it tries to unlock then it get exception.
**It will not have any effect on execution or locking of first thread which is acquiring the lock.**

- **Same thread:**

  - Lock:  If same thread which is acquiring the lock again tries to acquire the lock then lock counter increments.
  - Unlock:   If same thread which is acquiring the lock tries to unlock then lock counter decrements and as soon as lock counter becomes 0, thread releases the lock.
- **Different thread:**

  - Lock:  If the lock is held by another thread then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until the lock has been acquired, at which time the lock hold count is set to one.
  - Unlock:  If different thread tries to `unlock` when it is NOT holding the lock then IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown.

That is the reason `ReentrantLock` lock and unlock mandates you to have try-catch or throw mechanism because it throws exception.

Read below excerpt from  `ReentrantLock#unlock()`

> If the current thread is the holder of this lock then the hold 
>   count is decremented.  If the hold count is now zero then the lock  is
>   released.  **If the current thread is not the holder of this  lock then
>   {@link IllegalMonitorStateException} is thrown**.

**Answer to second question:**

> I think a lock should be acquired and released in the function itself,
>   before the control is returned from the function. Is my understanding
>   correct?

That's the whole purpose of `ReentrantLock`, you can extend the locking mechanism to other methods, which you cannot do with synchronized blocks and methods. See below from [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

> A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and
>   semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized
>   methods and statements, **but with extended capabilities**.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: @EJP Updated for remove code format and put in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

> What if somebody just calls method2 when i am already executing method1/method2 pair? Doesn't it complicate things.

`java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` is a more powerful mechanism than `synchronized`.  Power tools are dangerous.  Use them with caution.

See @hagrawal's answer for details.

Comment: *"Power tools are dangerous. Use them with caution."* True.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example instead:

```
public class Test {
    ...
    public void method1() {
       l.lock();
       ...
    }

    public void method2() {
       l.lock();
       ...
       while (l.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
         l.unlock();
       }
    }
}
```

This setup means that once Thread A calls `method1()`, Thread B will block when calling any of the methods until Thread A calls `method2()`. So the lock scope spans zero or more invocations of `method1()` followed by a single invocation of `method2()`.

Though in practice I would consider it far easier and cleaner to write code that restricts lock scope to a single method or part of a method.

Comment: This won't work! The reentrant lock needs one `unlock()` per `lock()`. Down vote.

Comment: @ciamej is right. `lock()` increments the lock count, and `unlock()` decrements the lock count.  The lock will only be released if the lock count goes to zero.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#unlock()

Comment: And this neatly demonstrates why it isn't a good idea to try wacky scopes for locks: it's very easy to get it wrong.